# bijective correspondence involing homomorphsims to a direct product of groups?

Tags: group-theory

Let $G$, $G'$ and $H$ be groups. Establish a bijective correspondence between homomorphisms $\Phi: H \to G \times G'$ from $H$ to the product group and pairs $(\varphi, \varphi')$ consisting of a homomorphism $\varphi: H \to G$ and a homomorphism $\varphi': H \to G'$.

I am confused as to what a bijective correspondence is referring to in this context.

Comment: What did you mean by "Gprime"? You should take 10 minutes to learn to type mathematics with LaTeX, otherwise it is very hard and discouraging to try to read your post...

Answer (score 2):

I think what you mean is this : Consider two homomorphisms $\varphi : H\to G$ and $\varphi' : H\to G'$, you get a map
$$
\Phi : H\to G\times G' \text{ given by } h \mapsto (\varphi(h), \varphi'(h))
$$
Conversely, given a map $\Phi : H\to G\times G'$, consider the projection homomorphisms
$$
\pi_1 : G\times G' \to G \text{ and } \pi_2 : G\times G'\to G'
$$
and set
$$
\varphi = \pi_1\circ \Phi, \text{ and } \varphi' = \pi_2\circ \Phi
$$
Then $\varphi$ and $\varphi'$ are group homomorphisms, and
$$
\Phi(h) = (\varphi(h), \varphi'(h)) \quad\forall h\in H
$$
This gives a bijection
$$
\text{Hom}(H,G\times G') \to \text{Hom}(H,G)\times \text{Hom}(H,G')
$$